# Sorting by Pro Keys rating

Tags: rock-band-3

When I'm playing Rock Band 3 by myself, I want to go into Quickplay and sort the songs by their difficulty in Pro Keys. I can't figure out how-- when I log in from the keyboard and choose "Song Difficulty" as the sort order, it uses the regular Keys difficulty until I've played a song in Pro Keys.

Is there a way to choose Pro Keys from the song sort/filter menu, and I just don't see it? Is there some other solution?

(I'm on Xbox, if that matters, and this is the keyboard controller that came in the game/keys bundle.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure "Sorted By" is set to "Song Difficulty." Next, You also need to set "Instrument Scores" to "Pro Keys." I tested this by setting Instrument Score to Keys, and it sorted by difficulty with normal keys. I then switched Instrument Scores to Pro Keys and it sorted by Pro Keys.

I tested this on the 360 version.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that-- thank you.